# How to shade recession periods in Stata?

Tags: stata

I'm trying to shade recession period as a backdrop to a lineplot, using a downloaded NBER dummy.

I use this line of code:

```
twoway area usrec year
```

and get this linked graph:

[image]

How can I make the graph use bars rather than spikes? (Variable is a dummy, it is 4 or zero)

Comment: `search recession` points to `bgshade` and `nbercycles`; see also https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1601600315 and https://blog.stata.com/2020/02/13/adding-recession-shading-to-time-series-graphs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick's comment is really the answer to this question.

Here is an example from `help nbercycles` by Christopher Baum.

First install `nbercycles` and `freduse` (for the MWE data) from SSC:

```
ssc install nbercycles
ssc install freduse
```

Then load the data and generate and `tsset` set a monthly date:

```
freduse MPRIME, clear
generate ym = mofd(daten)
tsset ym, monthly
```

Then plot the prime rates and shade the recessions:

```
nbercycles MPRIME if tin(1970m1,1990m1), ///
    file(nber2.do) replace
```

[image: nber rates]